# Fiddler displaying server information on http 411 status

Tags: asp.net, fiddler

I am facing an issue to overcome. In my ASP.Net application testing team had posted an issue that they are getting server information which must not be displayed.
Steps they used are

1. They have open fiddler and application in the browser.
2. After getting the URL in fiddler right click on the URL.
3. Select "**Replay**" then "**Reissue from Composure**"
4. In the Composer tab select "**Option**" tab and uncheck fix "**Content-length header**".
5. Now select "**Parsed**" tab and option "**Post**" from the drop-down option.
6. Click on **Execute**.

In Response header, it will show Server Information(Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0)
I have added several tags in web.config and global.asax to hide my server details it is not displaying for status 200 but not working for status 411.

I have tried following methods, which is working if HTTP status is 200. but not working for status 411.

1. In global.asax
   HttpContext.Current.Response.Headers.Set("Server", "");
   Response.Headers.Remove("Server");
2. In web.config

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to remove information from Server Error pages in ASP.NET 4.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29372625/is-it-possible-to-remove-information-from-server-error-pages-in-asp-net-4-0)